# SQLITE Query AVG SubSelect / Join

Tags: sqlite, join, average

I tried my best, but I'm not able to deal with this :)
I have two tables, I try to compare the AVG Data from Table one with the Data2 from Table2.

Table1

| Name | Data |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 1 |
| AA | 5 |
| AA | 10 |
| AB | 10 |
| AB | 50 |
| AB | 100 |

AVG AA = 5.333...
AVG AB = 53.333...

Table2

| Name2 | Data2 |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 4 |
| AB | 50 |

The output I want:

| Name | Data | Name2 | Data2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 5.333... | AA | 4 |
| AB | 53.333 | AB | 50 |

I tried something like this...

```
SELECT (SELECT AVG(Data) FROM Table1) AS AVGData, (SELECT Name FROM Table1) AS Name, Table2.*, FROM "Table2"
GROUP BY Table2.Name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that both tables contain the same names, you must aggregate in `Table1` and then join to `Table2`:

```
SELECT t2.*, t1.* 
FROM (
  SELECT Name, AVG(Data) Data 
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY Name
) t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t2.Name2 = t1.Name
```